# Why d3.csv() convert first row into array and the others rows into objects?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using last version (d3.v5.min.js) in my html page, and in JavaScript I want to parse a csv file.My csv file is like this (6 items on first row, 6 items on second row):

```
x,A,B,C,B,D
a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
```

I try to load the data like this:

```
d3.csv("path/to/file.csv").then(function(inputData) {
    console.log(inputData);
}
```

And this will be printed in console:

```
Array(1)
    0:
        A: "a1"
        B: "a4"
        C: "a3"
        D: "a5"
        x: "a0"
        __proto__: Object
    columns: Array(6)
        0: "x"
        1: "A"
        2: "B"
        3: "C"
        4: "B"
        5: "D"
        length: 6
        __proto__: Array(0)
        length: 1
       __proto__: Array(0)
```

That means, there are 6 columns and just 5 values now (duplicate keys in objects are ignored and only last one is used).
Why is like this? Not sure if this is the best place to ask, but in my case this implementation produce unexpected results.

Comment: like you say, how can you have duplicate keys in a CSV file? does 1 attribute have 2 values?

Comment: @rioV8 I was expecting also the columns to ignore the duplicate key too. To answer to your question: it can happens :)

Comment: the row is created by setting the field with key=`column[i]` equal to the value. Just extract the keys of the first record and use these.